# Connection to Service in Stackblitz dont work

Tags: angular, typescript, stackblitz

Goal:
Make a connection with service named Data in stackblitz.

Problem:
It doesn't work. what part am I missing?

Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mpy6pr

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ytzk2a?file=src/app/app.component.ts

You were missing this part, you need to reference the file not just the folder:

[image]

Comment: Additionally, OP can create `index.ts` in the services folder and export the data.service. See [barrels](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/tips/barrel.html).

Comment: This answer would not work, as there will be errors in the console. `ERROR
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[DataService -> HttpClient]:
StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[DataService -> HttpClient]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!` since the *HttpClientModule* is not imported.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems:

1. Import the *HttpClientModule* in your `app.module.ts`

   ```
   import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";

   @NgModule({
     imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpClientModule],
     ...
   })
   ```
2. Next fix the import in `app.component.ts`

   ```
   import { DataService } from './_services/data.service';
   ```

[Forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sz8dsa?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: @What'sUP: Updated the answer to include a *working stackblitz*.